# While using this library (FastPwmPin.h) output frequency is coming exactly but not duty ratio?

Tags: power-supply, arduino, power, pwm, duty-cycle

I am doing a simple power supply for that I need PWM signal to turn ON and OFF the MOSFET. For this I am using arduino UNO for PWM signal generation. So I used a library called FastPwmPin.h to generate PWM singal of frequency (145 KHz) in the PWM pins. I am getting the exact frequency as per the code but duty is not chnaging. That is even if I chnage the duty ratio in the code function the output duty is fixed in DSO (digital storage oscilloscope). I don't why it is happening like this. My issue is the duty ratio is not changing as per library code.

**MY REQUIREMENT IS PWM SIGNAL OF 145 KHz and duty ratio of 70% **

The arduino code which I am [image]using is attached below.

The FAST PWM library link can be found here: https://github.com/maxint-rd/FastPwmPin

Comment: Which Arduino you are using? Have you read the library manual/documentation about what features are supported on your Arduino and on the specific pin you are using?

Comment: Hi I am using Arduino uno (Atmega 328p) basic version

Answer (score 5):

If you read the documentation of your Library you will find, that pins 9 and 11 only support "toggle mode" (50% duty). Use pin 3 or 10 instead and read the documentation.

Comment: Hi stromi I even checked in pin 3 and 10 it is coming only 50 % duty ratio

Comment: Ya ok stromi1011. My only issue is the duty ratio. Frequency I am able to get as per the code. If you have any Arduino library which can generate 145KHz and 70% duty ratio kindly share me it will be very helpful.